# Spring Thymeleaf + Textarea

Tags: html, spring, textarea, thymeleaf

I created form with one input text and one `textarea`. The input text works fine, but textarea isn't even displayed:

```
<div id="news" th:fragment="admin_panel">
    <form method="POST" th:action="@{/addNews}" th:object="${news}" id="myform">
        Tytuł:
        <input type="text" th:field="*{title}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Wstaw"/>
    </form>
    <textarea name="news_content" rows="20" cols="80" th:field="${news.content}" form="myform">
        ...
    </textarea>
</div>
```

When I delete the `th:field` the `textarea` is displayed and when I use `th:value` instead of `th:field` it's displayed too but doesn't save the written text to news.content (news.title is saved ok).

I don't have any idea... I read thymeleaf references but can't find answer, so please help good people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the selected object expression `*{content}` AND place the textarea tag inside the form tag!

In the end its all about the generated `name` attribute in the resulting form. The name needs to correspond to the `propertyAccessor` from the selected root object `th:object`.
The form is processed by spring (without any thymeleaf interception).

The docs about spring integration are really good: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html

They state this:

Values for th:field attributes must be selection expressions (*{...}), which makes sense given the fact that they will be evaluated on the form-backing bean and not on the context variables (or model attributes in Spring MVC jargon).

---

**EDIT**:
Thanks to the link to the project, the fix was easy:

- Thymeleaf 3.0.0.BETA03 had a bug in the textarea processor, moving to 3.0.0.RELEASE fixed this issue
- Additionally I have moved the textarea inside the form element.

Comment: not working :/ ... Besides in my opinion ${news.content}  is equal to *{content} when we used th:object = ${news}. Any other solutions ?

Comment: In fact i would have said that you should even get an exception from thymeleaf, but thats just from my memory. Th:field "needs" a object expression. Probably you have a typo / false character and the expression is never evaluated? Take a look at the final result and post it here, using th:field

Comment: About exceptions :

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/eniupage] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.SpringTextareaFieldTagProcessor' (template: "templates/fragments" - line 144, col 60)] with root cause java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Comment: Updated the answer with more details. -----
Without the code of your (simplified) model, requestmapping and resulting html form, we will mot be able to help you further.

Comment: Ok I added my controller classes and domain object.

Comment: Ahh, now i see it :) your textarea is NOT within the form! At least in the fragment you posted here. Move it inside and use `th:field="*{content}"` and you should be fine.

Comment: Ehh I tried it too :(
Actually html code in my edited answer.

Comment: I dont really know what is wroing in this form and textarea. I included this textarea into form and used *{} but still textarea isn't displayed :(

Comment: Here you are link to whole project:
https://github.com/skax/eniupage

Maybe it helps you to find whats wrong.

Comment: And voila. Found it. You used the beta version of thymeleaf which had a bug. Pull-request created ;)

Answer (score 4):

My textarea input was working fine when i was saving some data through it(in clean state when i was performing a save to DB) but in case of edit form(where my textarea input was supposed to show the prefilled description from the model property book.description) was blank, the reason for that was the th:value attribute, i changed it to the th:field attribute and it started working as expected.

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="description" rows="5"
                              name="description"
                              placeholder="Description" th:field="${book.description}"
                              required="required"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the form text field. Linking the textarea with the form by the form id is sufficient.

```
<textarea rows="8" cols="120" name="lines" form="usrform" th:text="${message}"></textarea>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/}" id="usrform">
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="submitlines">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="action=submitlines")
public String handleForm(
        @RequestParam("lines") String input,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About exceptions :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/eniupage] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.SpringTextareaFieldTagProcessor' (template: "templates/fragments" - line 144, col 60)] with root cause
    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
```

In my form, there are text input and textarea as You see. `news.title` is saved ok, but `news.content` don't. When I replace for test these parameters (in the text input I use `news.content` and in the textarea there is `th:field = ${news.title}`) it works well too. Maybe should I use another expression instead of `th:field`?

News.java

```
package eniupage.domain;

public class News 
{
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private Date date;
    
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) 
    {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public Date getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }
    
}
```

HomeController.java

```
package eniupage.web;

@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/" )
public class HomeController  
{
    
    @Autowired
    AddNewsService addNewsService;
    
    @RequestMapping( method = GET )
    public String home( Model model )
    {
        model.addAttribute( "newses", addNewsService.getNewses() );
        return "home";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping( value = "/addNews", method = POST )   
    public String addNews( News news )
    {
        addNewsService.addNews( news );
        return "redirect:/";
    }
     
}
```

AdminController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/admin" )
public class AdminController  
{    
    @RequestMapping( method = GET )
    public String admin( Model model )
    {
        model.addAttribute( new News() );
        return "admin";
    }
         
}
```

There isn't any resulting of HTML form, because it isn't even displayed in div. There are only text input and submit button.

Edited html:

```
<form action="#" method = "POST" th:action="@{/addNews}" th:object = "${news}" id = "myform">
        
            Tytuł: <input type = "text" th:field = "*{title}" />
            
            <input type = "submit" value = "Add" /></br>
            
            <textarea  rows = "20" cols = "80" th:field = "*{content}" form = "myform" >... </textarea>
            
            
        </form>
```

I'm using `thymeleaf 3.0`. Maybe this is the reason?

In reference I read :

> The th:field attribute behaves differently depending on whether it is attached to an ,  or  tag (and also depending on the specific type of  tag).

But I can't find what is this difference between using `th:field` in input and textarea.